# 20.04: Start Ubuntu Server with Graphics Card removed

Tags: boot, server, ssh

I have just installed Ubuntu server on a machine and had to install a graphics card to complete the installation process. However, now that installation is done, I would like to remove the card as it is unnecessary. When I tried to ssh into the server with the graphics card removed, I was unable to ssh, indicating to me that the server did not successfully start up. When I turned it off and put the card back in, it booted successfully. Is there some configuration I need to modify in order to successfully boot without the graphics card?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Not really, I just accepted that it needs a graphic card.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what you describe. You can check out the steps [here](https://facorazza.com/snippets/ubuntu-server-2004-installation-without-gpu/). Let me know if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Since the linked page ( https://facorazza.com/snippets/ubuntu-server-2004-installation-without-gpu/ ) is not available anymore, here's a Ubuntu pastebin link I have created from the cached page, just in case if anyone needs it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FQ6YVmwRDb/