# remove graphics card from ubuntu server machine

Tags: server, graphics, gpu, headless

I used a old HP media PC to install Ubuntu Linux 20.04.3 and removed the video card and restart the machine. The server boots after making several beeps. I guess it is because I removed the graphics card. Is there any way to remove this GPU check during bootup?

Comment: Since the link ( https://facorazza.com/snippets/ubuntu-server-2004-installation-without-gpu/ ) you were looking for on other thread ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236350/20-04-start-ubuntu-server-with-graphics-card-removed ) is not available anymore, here's a Ubuntu pastebin link I have created with the contents from the cached page: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FQ6YVmwRDb/

Comment: Thank you @Jags. Unfortunately, this method didn't stop the initial beeps. Maybe it is not just graphics card as I thought.